# How can I display text in A-Frame?

Tags: webvr, aframe

For http://aframe.io/, how can I render text without having to create an image?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**EDIT:** A text component has landed in A-Frame master branch. This will roll out in 0.5.0. The component will have support for fonts, alignments, anchors, baselines, shaders, etc. `<a-entity text="value: HELLO"></a-entity>` https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/text.html

You can use some of the community components:

- https://github.com/bryik/aframe-bmfont-text-component - Text drawn using signed distance field fonts (bitmap fonts that look great regardless of zoom level).
- https://npmjs.com/package/aframe-text-geometry-component - Text geometries.
- https://github.com/maxkrieger/aframe-textwrap-component - Draw component focused on text wrapping.
- https://github.com/scenevr/htmltexture-component - HTML canvas as a texture.

I recommend the Bitmap Font Text Component which is performant and looks visually good:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/bryik/aframe-bmfont-text-component/master/dist/aframe-bmfont-text-component.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-entity bmfont-text="text: HELLO!; color: #333" position="0 0 -5"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```