# Adding pop-up text in A-Frame

Tags: javascript, aframe

How to add text in 360 degree photos using A-Frame 
The text should be like a **popup message** when the cursor goes to any icons it should popup the text

**Example**: consider that I am in kitchen when the cursor is goes to kitchen icon it should popup the text "kitchen"

Thanks in  advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display text in A-Frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276726/how-can-i-display-text-in-a-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event listener to show text.

```
document.querySelector('#yourHotspot').addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
  document.querySelector('#yourText').setAttribute('visible', true);
});
```

Comment: Without using css we can do this?